# Capture High Resolution Screen Shot for Unity Game

Tags: unity, marketing, screenshot

I'm working on a mobile game. We need some HD screen shot to use in our **press kit**. I'd like to know, how do we capture HD screen shot of games inside **unity's editor**. Resolution **must support printing quality of banners** that we would use to showcase our game in local game expo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post on Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/722773/how-do-i-take-a-super-high-res-screenshot.html) there are/were some issues with huge screenshots.

But they suggest using this [(FREE) asset (Instant Screenshot)](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/24122) from the asset store.
Give it a try and let us know if that works for you (and which resolution you created with).

Comment: Link dead as our democracy